# Jcarousel и addClass('active')

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
Возникла следующая задача в карусели (на базе jcarousel). Крутятся баннеры, текст и прочая инфа по кругу с автопрокруткой (не суть). Есть статичная кнопка "Заказать". Дабы не плодить "сущностей", и кнопка, и форма - одни на странице.

В самой карусельке есть

```
<input type="hidden" value="Разные названия" class="hidden-name"/>
```

который, собственно, мне и отдает название каждого слайда.

Смотрю на

```
$('.slider_order.top').click(function() {
            alert($('.hidden-name').val());
        });
```

и вижу только самое первое название.

Решил смотреть на `.slider_order.top.active`, а вот как каждому текущему, видимому сладу присвоить класс active, никак допереть не могу. Не жрет jcarousel его.

Резюме: как добавить текущему слайду класс active и только текущему?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо придумывать велосипед, его уже придумали: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/control/reference/events.html